# Mapping a Topbar Menu Item in SwiftUI app to opening a specific bundled PDF?

Tags: macos, pdf, swiftui

SwiftUI, macOS:

I'm trying to get a menu item to open "default PDF viewer of your choice", with a specific bundled PDF.

Here's what I have thus far:

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit
import PDFKit


func Guide1(_ sender: Any) {
    if let pdfURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Guide1", withExtension: "pdf"){
        if NSWorkspace.shared.open(pdfURL) {
    }
}
}

func Guide2(_sender: Any) {
    if let pdfURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Guide2", withExtension: "pdf"){
        if NSWorkspace.shared.open(pdfURL) {
    }
}
}
```

Now, what I'm missing is how to call these functions.

From previous tutorials, I've found that one way of getting the menu items to "do something" is to ctrl-click and drag the Menu Item entry to First Responder, and then select functions from the list. However, these Guide1 + Guide2 functions are not displayed.

Other tutorials suggest using `@IBAction` - but the minute I type that into a SwiftUI app, an error tells me to  get the `@IBaction` replaced with "nothing". So I cannot use those either.

So, are these even valid strings for opening a PDF - and if so, how do I connect a dropdown menu item so that these PDFs are opened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It needs to be added not in SwiftUI view but, for example and simplest, in AppDelegate as below

```
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBAction func Guide1(_ sender: Any) {
            if let pdfURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Guide1", withExtension: "pdf"){
                if NSWorkspace.shared.open(pdfURL) {
            }
        }
    }
```

then in your Main.storyboard (or XIB) just CTRL-drag from menu item to `FirstResponder` and `Guide1` action is there to bind (sometime build might be required before that, but as tested on Xcode 11.2 it just works).

Comment: Thank you! This solved it. I'm now able to make a PDF open from a Main Menu item, and it opens in, say, Preview or other things. Much appreciated. I'm going to mark this as solved :))